# How can i get Essential matrix from Rotation matrix for drawing epipolar line?

Tags: python, fundamental-matrix

**Goal**
Ultimately,i want to draw epipolar line on right image.

**Question**
If i know points on left image and rotation matrix between left camera and right camera, how can i get Essential matrix for drawing epipolar line on right image?
(so, i don't use 8-points algorithm)

I don't know points on right image and translate.

Also, if i don't know Intrinsic parameter, can i draw epipolar line?

Thank you to read my ask.

Given the following code, information

```
import numpy as np
human_joints = [[555.386  , 404.46036],
    [530.7022 , 406.29446],
    [525.9443 , 495.40973],
    [524.181  , 567.4924],
    [580.57495, 402.6036],
    [570.3312 , 490.75363],
    [565.38043, 574.8825],
    [552.14886, 357.5693],
    [558.4907 , 305.46155],
    [550.31824, 286.06784],
    [553.5209 , 265.68933],
    [581.8808 , 324.2853],
    [592.437  , 379.61853],
    [585.6859 , 423.94284],
    [532.6373 , 319.59055],
    [513.3627 , 373.28836],
    [497.28082, 419.97885]]

K_l = np.array([[1.14967570e+03, 0.00000000e+00, 5.08848622e+02],
   [0.00000000e+00, 1.14759162e+03, 5.08064917e+02],
   [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]])

K_r = np.array([[1.14551134e+03, 0.00000000e+00, 5.14968197e+02],
       [0.00000000e+00, 1.14477393e+03, 5.01882019e+02],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]])

R = np.array([[ 0.7133686 ,  0.10367816, -0.69307726],      # left to right 
            [-0.15670811,  0.98755177, -0.01356717],
            [ 0.68304305,  0.11828922,  0.72073563]])

print(right_img.shape) # (1002,1000,3)
print(left_img.shape) # (1002,1000,3)
```

I can't know how can i get Essential matrix or fundamental matrix by using Rotation matrix